# Adding multiple products to cart (multiple post buttons at once)

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to post multiple add to cart buttons in javascript with single button click? Here is my code for single add to cart buttons:

```
<div class="buy_now" style="margin: 1em 0;">
    <?php echo functions::form_draw_form_begin('buy_now_form', 'post'); ?>
    <?php echo functions::form_draw_hidden_field('product_id', $product_id); ?>

   <?php if (!$catalog_only_mode) { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label><?php echo language::translate('title_quantity', 'Quantity'); ?></label>
      <div style="display: flex">
        <div class="input-group">
          <?php echo (!empty($quantity_unit['decimals'])) ? functions::form_draw_decimal_field('quantity', isset($_POST['quantity']) ? true : 1, $quantity_unit['decimals'], 1, null) : (functions::form_draw_number_field('quantity', isset($_POST['quantity']) ? true : 1, 1)); ?>
          <?php echo !empty($quantity_unit['name']) ? '<div class="input-group-addon">'. $quantity_unit['name'] .'</div>' : ''; ?>
        </div>
        <div>
          <?php echo '<button class="processed" name="add_cart_product" value="true" type="submit"'. (($quantity <= 0 && !$orderable) ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '') .'>'. language::translate('title_add_to_cart', 'Add To Cart') .'</button>'; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php echo functions::form_draw_form_end(); ?>
  </div>
```

And I have another button, which I would like to add all items at once(it's doesnt do anything right now):

```
<?php echo '<button id="triggerAll" class="btn" name="add_cart_product_all" value="true" type="submit">'. language::translate('title_add_to_cart', 'Add To Cart') .'</button>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you aren't able to make multiple POST requests with standard browser call. You'll have to do it with JavaScript which makes Ajax POST calls on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
<script>
$('#triggerAll').on('click',function(){
    $('.processed').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```